# Force a default datetime format in ms access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, date-formatting

I'm currently porting a Access 2003 app to use a SQL Server 2005 back-end, and I'm having trouble with the datetime representations.

As I understand it, the default Access behavior is to use the datetime format defined on the local machine's regional settings, as do SQL-Server.  Is there a way to force Access to use another default format (other than those available in the "Format" property dropdown list), something like Format = "dd/mm/yyyy"?

My problem is that a good many forms in the app have sub-forms whose data is linked to the parent via relation implying datetime and numeric values (terrible design, I know.)

Now, when retrieving the data, the date will print ok, using a yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss format, but I cannot make new entries, or inserts from the forms as SQL server will complain that the text-data overflowed the capacity for a datetime, or that the engine cannot find the parent record.

I'm using a file-based DSN to connect to the backend.

Thanks for any insight in the matter,
Pascal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates are stored in MS Access as numbers. You can set custom formats for controls, such as `dd/mm/yyyy`, but it nearly always means a deeper problem.

[image]

More info: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/format-property-date-time-data-type-HA001232739.aspx

Comment: Do you mean, by setting the "Format" property for a field?  Because it seems to me, that all the options available are different format for the localized version as defined in the Regional Properties, such as "Date, General", "Date, Short", and so on.  If I try to put a formatting string there; only the string gets displayed.  I know that dates are stored as numbers, but I think that when sent to SQL Server through the ODBC connection, the string query gets parsed, and that's where it fails.

Comment: No, I mean for a control on a form, not a field in a table. You can set custom formats for fields in tables, but it is a fatal error. You mention that you are working with forms, if you must set a format, do it on the form.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke.  I was refering to the control on the form, and as stated, the format property do not seems to accept Format Strings other than those mentioned in the dropdown list.
Edit : I got it to accept a format string by affecting the property programmatically; i couldn't do it from the UI's Properties panel.

Comment: Well I am glad you got something that worked for you, and thanks for the vote, but you can use the format property, if you wish. I have added an illustration.